# How to block certain devices from showing up for AirPlay / Screen Mirroring?

Tags: macos, airplay, big-sur

As of MacOS 11 (Big Sur) the Airplay/Screen Mirroring options have changed. In Catalina there was a single icon in the toolbar for Airplay, clicking it gave a list of devices that, AFAIK, didn't change while the menu was held down.

In MacOS 11, the new flow is you click the control panel(?) icon, then "screen mirroring", then a list of devices appears.

[image]

This list is populated as you're interacting with it which has the problem that you intend to choose a name but just has you go to click, new devices are added and you click on the wrong device.

Worse, these devices could be from other houses/rooms/apartments. Serveral times now, trying to click on my own device, Big Sur has added devices under the mouse as I click and I've ended up clicking on a neighbor's device. Which, if I understand correctly, means I've just interrupted my neighbor's viewing and possibly made their TV, which was off, come on.

How can I block certain devices from ever appearing in the screen mirroring list of devices so I can avoid annoying my neighbors?

Note: Turing Bluetooth off is not an option as I use Airpod with my Mac daily.